# How to use facebook api with Flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm building an app with flutter that can share image (with text) on multiple social media (i'm beginning with instagram and facebook stories).

I managed to share images using the package social_share, but i can't send text.
And i can't find another package that allow me to share directly on the right social media with the text/sticker options...
I guess i have to use facebook api to do that but i can't find a right tutorial to use the api for sharing content (all my search redirect me on login options with facebook api)

Do you have any clue or good tutorial to help?

I have added the facebook sdk to the android folder but i'm missing how to use it on my dart files

thanks for your time!

Comment: I guess you didn't find one ?